# Passing list from Client side Controller to Server side Controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is this the correct way of passing list from client side controller to server side controller. It's not working.

JavaScript Controller

```
    handleSaveQuestions: function(cmp, event, helper) {

    var action = cmp.get("c.saveQuestions");

    alert(cmp.get("v.QuestionList").length);//displays 12, which is correct

    action.setParams({ questionList : cmp.get("v.QuestionList") });
    action.setParams({ Questionnaire : cmp.get("v.Questionnaire") });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
```

Apex Controller

```
    public static void saveQuestions(List<QuestionWrap> questionList, 
    Questionnaire__c Questionnaire){

    System.debug('questionList'+questionList.size());//displays 0, should have been 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that I was setting action.setParams twice for two variables which seems to be wrong. Following change worked.

```
    action.setParams({ questionList : cmp.get("v.QuestionList"), Questionnaire : cmp.get("v.Questionnaire") });
```